# Minimalistic graphical interface to control variables during a long computation

Tags: python, matlab, pyqt5

I want to have a simple graphical interface to control variables used in a long computation in Python. Let me explain the problem, and show a solution, in MATLAB, that I know better. I am rather a beginner in python.

I have this function `f` that uses a variable `x`.

```
function f

x = 1;
for n = 1:10
  fprintf('%f\n', x)
  pause(1)
end

end
```

I want to be able to change the value of `x` during the computation with a graphical interface. In Matlab, this can be done relatively consisely. I need first to make `x` a `global` variable, then create a widget with a simple callback that updates `x`. The final code is:

```matlab
function computation_with_gui
% the main function simply creates the control and calls f.
    uicontrol('Style', 'slider', 'Min', 0, 'Max', 100, 'Position', [0 0 400 20], 'Callback', @callback)
    f();
end

function callback(h, d)
% the callback simply updates x
    global x
    x = h.Value;
end

function f
% function f now declares x as global
    global x
    x = 1;
    for n = 1:10
        fprintf('%f\n', x)
        pause(1)
    end
end
```

The script above displays a slider (could be another widget, unimportant here) and launches the computation. The slider is not freezed during the computation, I can use it to control the value of `x` that is displayed by `f`. Finally, the program stops when `f` completes. Overall, the code needed to add this simple graphical interface to `f` is really minimal.

My question is, how to do something similar in Python? I clearly favor conciseness in the present case. My preference would go to PyQt5 (simply because it comes with my configuration), but if another framework would enable something more concise, that is fine too. Again, the widget would be something else than a slider if that makes things easier.

Comment: Use the [guidata](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guidata) package. It is based on PyQt5 so it is trivial to install for you.

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial on Python GUIs? Because that's what it looks like.

Comment: @mad-physicist Not really. Matlab can provide a working GUI for my task in about 10 lines. I am asking whether that is possible in python as well. Learning to write GUIs is a broader and more complicated problem. My Matlab code, for example, does not really require proper Matlab GUI knowledge.

Comment: Short answer is yes, you could probably do something very similar to what you have here.

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or 2?

Comment: Python 3 -- forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something very similar to what you have in MATLAB. I will adapt the [PyQt slider example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qslider_widget_signal.htm) from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/) to demonstrate:

```
import sys, threading, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QSlider, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

x = 1

class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.slider.setValue(x)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self.slider.setTickInterval(5)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.valuechange)

    def valuechange(self):
        global x
        x = self.slider.value()

def process(gui):
    for n in range(10):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(1)
    gui.close()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GUI()
    gui.show()
    threading.Thread(target=process, args=(gui,)).start()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, there are some differences here. For one thing, the task has to be started in a background thread because main thread will get blocked by [`app.exec`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec). For another, the processing function needs to have a way to let the GUI know it is done, which I implemented by passing in a reference to the GUI window.

While using global variables is generally a bad idea, I have used it here as a direct translation from the MATLAB code.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks.